# Create one filter by combining two regex patterns with AND condition

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Google Analytics has a way to Exclude and Include users when creating custom reports, by selecting drop down pre-set options that will allow one to apply Exclude and Include conditions.

I have two Segments created in Google Analytics as below.

Segment #1 - Using Exclude option in GA with following pattern:

/(a|l|lo|log-o|b|ap|u|bo|su|un|bl|spRe|bi|inEm|al|n|c|w|sta|tmp($|/)|dvs$|m_c|d_t)|(ap|s|t|dew).web.com|ps.io|md.com|aza.com

Segment #2 - Using Include option in GA with following pattern:

ap.web.com/dew|dew.web.com

I want to create one segment for reporting that includes both the above listed regex patterns with an AND condition - so when applied, it excludes segment pattern #1 and includes segment pattern #2

Comment: Does anyone have any thoughts/suggestions to my post?

Answer (score 0):

I think GA has a straight forward way of doing this? See screenshot. Were you looking for something else?

[image]